# Convert (window.crypto.subtle.generateKey)-key to aes-js key

Tags: javascript, encryption, aes, cryptoapi, webcrypto-api

Suppose I use the following code to generate aes-256-cbc key, but how to use this key in aes-js?

```
window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
  {
    name: "AES-CBC",
    length: 256
  },
  true,
  ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
).then((key) => {
  //How to convert the key to aes-js key (Array or Uint8Array or Buffer)
});
```

Comment: You must export the key, [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/exportKey#raw_export).